# UIButton in UIView inside UIScrollView does to receive touch events when outside original frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I've been reading similar posts all morning, but could not find an answer to my problem.
As title says, I have several UIButton-s in UIView that is a child of a UIScrollView. I set the contentSize for the scrollview, and I can scroll and see all contents of UIView, however, I cannot click any of the buttons that are not visible originally (buttons that are visible from the beginning work just fine).

I tried setting the frame of the child UIView, and interactions are enabled inn all views.

Anything else that I'm missing?

thank you!!!

Comment: Can you share some code.. it ll be easier then.

Comment: Are you also setting the size of the UIView? Give it a background color so you can see if your buttons are inside its bounds.

Comment: Solved! Thanks everyone for the feedback. The secret is indeed to make sure you adjust the frame of the view. I thought I originally did it, but my own framework tried to outsmart me and hence reverted it back :)

Comment: You should answer your own question with this comment.  I will upvote it!!